# Autodesk Forge - Error translating source file to .obj

Tags: curl, autodesk-forge

I am working on a project in which I have to convert a .3ds to .obj using Autodesk Forge (online) APIs. I am following [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-source-file-to-obj/) tutorial. I successfully created an app, got the 2 token authorization and uploaded the .3ds file. However, in STEP 2 of the above mentioned tutorial, I get a HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request error. Following is the command which I type on the command line:

```
curl -X "POST" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJjbGllbnRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXnRzdyJ9.HuL9tWTk-1uWxHEJxFkybUIHKCboXXDPDEyry8374sI" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job" -d "{\"input\":{\"urn\":\"dXJXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXQ6YW5vdGhlcmp0YnVja2V0L0Nva2UuM2Rz\"},\"output\":{\"formats\":[{\"type\":\"obj\"}]}}"
```

According to my experience, this error only occurs when the command is invalid (an extra space, invalid delimiter etc.) I have gone over the command quite a few times but I don't see any errors. Can someone point out whats wrong with the above command?

Comment: I found the answer to this. Turns out, I had to add a \ before the comma (just before output). However, now I get HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized: The token has expired or is invalid, although I am using the same token for uploading the file and other stuff (which works fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/):

> **modelGuid**: Required for geometry extractions. The model view ID (guid). Currently only valid for 3d views.
>
> **objectIds**: Required for geometry extractions. List object ids to be translated. -1 will extract the entire model. Currently only valid for 3d views.

To translate to OBJ you first need to translate to SVF, then [get the modelGuid](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET/) for the 3D view(s) you want. Then you can use the following, which works fine.

I'm using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), you can also use [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/).

[image: POST Job for OBJ]